# What browser features are required to ask a question on security.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, asking-questions

What is minimal set of browser features required to ask a question on security.stackexchange.com without a user account?

Specifically, I use [Pale Moon portable](http://www.palemoon.org/palemoon-portable.shtml) as an ephemeral browser (it has no persistant data). I was attempting to post a question on security.stackexchange.com without logging into my user account, but I was unsuccessful.

Instead I received "Oh tin of pink meat / I ponder what you may be / Snout or ear or feet?" at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/submit
[image: Am I SPAM?]

Some browser settings:

```
Tools->Options->General->Manage Add-ons...
NoScript

Tools->Options->Content->
enabled 'Block pop-up windows' no exceptions
disabled 'Load images automatically' no exceptions
enabled 'Enable JavaScript' 

Tools->Options->Applications
"Podcast" 'Preview in Palemoon'
"Video Podcast" 'Preview in Palemoon'
"Web Feed"'Preview in Palemoon'
all remaining are 'Always ask'

Tools->Options->Privacy
Pale Moon will: "Never remember history"

Tools->Options->Security
enabled "Warn me when sites try to install add-ons" no exceptions

Passwords
disabled "Remember a password for sites"
disabled "Use a master password"

Tools->Options->Advanced->General
enabled "Warn me when web sites try to redirect or reload the page"

Tools->Options->Advanced->Network
Offline Storage
"Use up to 0 MB of space for the cache" 
enabled "Tell me when a website asks to store data for offline use" no exceptions
```

Comment: I have no idea for an answer, but I want a screenshot of that spam screen!

Comment: @AviD ask and ye shall receive

Comment: aww... was hoping for some cool pic :(

Comment: Still kinda cool though...

Answer (score 1):

FYI, JavaScript being disabled will hurt you *a lot*. This is one of our primary "you are a bot" tests.

Also I *STRONGLY* suggest you log in, as the tests are far stricter for anonymous and unregistered users, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This question does not describe my normal usage for stackexchange sites. I have several browers configured differently. My ephemeral browser on Windows is as described in the question. I was using it on stack exchange to see what the minimum set of required browser features is. For security profesionals who are interested in a high degree of anonymity, I would like to be able to describe a minimal browser configuration. Asking questions anonymously seems a lower bar than answering questions anonymously, so I started there.

Comment: I actually frequently browse web pages without JavaScript, Java, flash, cookies, automatic redirrection, images, cache, etc. Often I find the information I am looking for faster. Sometimes a website is unusable without all those features. My typical reaction is usually to go somewhere else, although on occasion I will enable the required features to see if the information is there.

Comment: Requiring Javascript is unfortunate, particularly on a security site, given how many security practitioners use NoScript.  (It is one thing to say "We encourage you to enable Javascript to get a better user experience"; it is another to say "You can't post questions to our site if Javascript is disabled".) If requiring Javascript is necessary to avoid spam, then that's just the way the cookie crumbles -- but it is still unfortunate. ... Recommending that users log in seems like good advice. If logging in removed the need for Javascript, that seems like it would be a great way to resolve it.

Comment: What sites do we need to be allowing JavaScript from, for minimal (i.e.: login, post Q&A/comments, vote, chat, flag) functionality?  Currently on this site, my NoScript has whitelisted `stackexchange.com`, `googleapis.com`, and `sstatic.net`.  Are any of these superfluous?

Comment: @iszi I would add `stackauth.com` to that as well