# What do I need in order to ask a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What browser features are required to ask a question on security.stackexchange.com?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/what-browser-features-are-required-to-ask-a-question-on-security-stackexchange-co)

I wonder what the minimum set of things to turn on is? Is it only JavaScript or are there additional requirements?